# Coding in SAS using dynamically changing variable

Tags: sas

I have a co-variance matrix of variables like this: The values are mirror image across diagonal line. Therefore below diagonal or upper diagonal can be made null for convenience. This is variance-co-variance matrix of the coefficients of a linear regression.

```
Obs Intercept   length  diameter    height  weight_w    weight_s
1   0.15510    -0.29969 -0.05904   -0.20594 0.07497    -0.00168
2   -0.29969    3.46991 -3.50836   -0.01703 -0.04841   -0.14048
3   -0.05904   -3.50836  5.08407   -0.82108 -0.13027    0.10732
4   -0.20594   -0.01703 -0.82108    4.89589 -0.29959    0.30447
5   0.07497    -0.04841 -0.13027   -0.29959  0.13787   -0.18763
6   -0.00168   -0.14048 0.10732    0.30447  -0.18763    0.40414
```

Where Obs 1 – 6 represent Intercept, and five variables length, diameter, height, weight_w, weight_s. Diagonal values are variances. Rest are co-variances between variables and variables and intercept.

I want to create a formula, where number of variables can change and user can input those as parameters. Based on number of variables formula should dynamically expand or contract and calculate result. The formula for five variables will be like this: C1,C2, ...C5 are constant that comes with five variables from outside. These are beta co-efficient of a linear regression. These will vary based on number of variables.

```
0.15+(C1)^2 * 3.46 + (C2)^2 * 5.08 + (C3)^2 * 4.89 + (C4)^2*0.13 + (C5)^2*0.40                   -- Covers all variances
+2*C1*-0.29 + 2*C2*-0.05 + 2*C3*-0.20 + 2*C4*-0.07 + 2*C5*-0.001                                       -- covers co-variance of all variables with intercept
+2*C1*C2*-3.50 + 2*C1*C3*-0.01 + 2*C1*C4*-0.04 + 2*C1*C5*-0.14                                      --covers co-variance of “length” with other leftover (minus intercept) variables
+2*C2*C3*-0.82+ 2*C2*C4*-0.13 + 2*C2*C5*0.10                                                                         -- covers co-variance of “diameter” with leftover variables
+2*C3*C4*-0.29+ 2*C3*C5*0.30                                                                                                         -- covers co-variance of “height” with leftovers     
+2*C4*C5*-0.18                                                                                                                                       -- covers co-variance of weight_w & weight_s
```

Those five constants, matching to five variables, are inserted from outside. Rest are coming from co-variance matrix. In the co-variance matrix table the diagonal values are variances of those variables. Rest are co-variances. In the formula, you can see that where there are variances I have taken square of constants (Cs). Where there are co-variance, of two variables involved, the respective constants (Cs) multiple. Intercept is another term that comes with these variables. But intercept doesn't have any "C".

For two variables the co-variance matrix will be like this: Intercept will be there too.

```
Obs Intercept  GRE         GPA 
1 1.15582    -.000281894  -0.28256 
2 -0.00028   0.000001118  -0.00011 
3 -0.28256   -.000114482  0.10213
```

Formula for calculation:

```
1.15582+(C1)^2 * 0.000001118 + (C2)^2 * 0.10213  -- Covers all variances on diagonal line
+2*C1*-.000281894 + 2*C2*-0.28256 -- covers co-variance of all variables with intercept
+2*C1*C2*-0.00011 -- covers co-variance between variable GRE & GPA
```

Comment: How do C1-C5 interact with your covariance matrix?  It's certainly possible to do what you're asking - as far as I can tell anyway - but it's entirely unclear precisely what you're asking.

Comment: Those five constants, matching to five variables, are inserted from outside. Rest are coming from co-variance matrix. In the co-variance matrix table the diagonal values are variances of those variables. Rest are co-variances. In the formula, you can see that where there are variances I have taken square of constants (Cs). Where there are co-variance, of two variables involved, the respective constants (Cs) multiple. Sorry I thought co-variance matrix is understood. Updating the question.

Comment: Why are there 5 variables C1-C5 but 6 variables in your CoV matrix?  I do understand what a covariance matrix is, but I don't understand how you relate C1-C5 with the six variables there.  The naming there is also a bit confusing as you have one column "Intercept"; is that an actual intercept or a variable called Intercept?

Comment: And, what exactly is dynamically changing?  Are there sometimes C1-C2 only, but still a 6x6 CoV matrix?

Comment: It looks like you're scoring something or doing matrix math? I would suggest showing this for a 2 x 2 matrix, 3 x 3 matrix etc so we can learn the rules to help implement this solution. You should also post what you've tried. Usually this will encompass using an array but should be relatively simple. Depending on the proc you may also have the CODE option to generate these statements.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify that. Intercept is a constant term that comes in any regression model. So if there are five variables in a regression then it will have five variables + one intercept. If there are two variables then: two variables + one intercept. I have taken co-variance matrix of all variables and intercept in a regression model and want to calculate this formula. Number of variables in regression model keep changing. The value of intercept will also change but it will always be there irrespective of number of variables. Hope this helps. Thanks for taking initiative.

Comment: So this is the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients of a linear regression?

Comment: Yes, Joe. I want to calculate confidence interval of predicted probabilities. In between I have to do these. I am new to SAS. Can write some trivial codes but not at this level.

Comment: Are you able to do this in SAS/IML?  Seems like it might be easier.  Also seems like it's likely that this can be derived from the PROCs themselves that created the regression coefficients, though I don't really know that side of things, but maybe one of the stats people would.

Comment: Using SAS I can generate predicted probabilities given new data sets. But we want to reuse beta co-efficients of existing linear regression (Cs) on new data sets and generate predicted probabilities. Therefore came up for this formula.

Comment: I assume you mean by 'existing linear regression' not something you built in your current SAS processes but have pre-existing? Otherwise if you develop a model you can definitely score new datasets with the build model.

Comment: You are right Reeza. I want to use existing beta coefficients for new data sets and calculate predicted probabilities.